# How to destroy a Bootstrap Carousel for mobile resolutions

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Is it possible to remove a bootstrap carousel (V 3.0.0 ) just when the resolution is below 768?

I used to do it on [CaroufredSel plugin](https://github.com/gilbitron/carouFredSel) but doesn't seem to work on bootstrap.

I am showing 4 elements per slide, but if i set the `#myCarousel` to `display:block;` i get one element below the other but only 4 elements are shown.

**EDIT**

Seems my question was missunderstood, I do not want to remove the elements or the carousel, i want to remove the functionality of the carousel itself, so the 12 elements overflow and are shown in block one below the other.

Comment: Would just hiding it or removing it work for you?

Comment: No it won't the carousel has 12 elements, show in a set of 4 by 4, below 768px i have to display them in block, (sounds weird but it's the customer request)

Comment: What do you mean by 'in a block'? Vertically? Individually rather than 4x4?

Comment: @AdamKewley Exactly, one below the other, and each in a 12 column grid (100%)

Comment: You can nest bootstrap grids however you need. Classes like `col-sm-3` will collapse as soon as the screen goes into the `xs` regime (e.g. below 766px, as you stated). So, with that in mind, I'd reccomend constructing your inner panel 4x4 using a bootstrap grid. There might be some wierd behaviors related to the carousel when doing that though, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Use media query aand override the carousel class?

Comment: Or use javascript `window.matchMedia` with width change listener to add or remove the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with jQuery using the following

```
$("#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item").css("display","block");
```

So using a viewport when the resolution is below 768px i set all the carousel item to display block, overriding the default display none that bootstrap applies.

Posting the answer in order to help someone else with the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

extending @DannyG answer, and keeping in mind the requirement of not destroying the elements, I solved the same problem using this code.

```
$("#carousel").carousel("pause"); //pause any transition animation
$("#carousel .carousel-inner > .item").css("display", "block"); //show hidden slides
$("#carousel .carousel-control").css("display", "none"); //hide left, right arrows
$("#carousel .carousel-indicators").css("display", "none"); // hide thumbnails at the bottoms
```

just displaying the hidden slides was not enough. I have to hide carousel controls as well. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

```css
  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { 
        .slide-hide-on-mobile { display: none; }
    }
```

```html
<section class="slider-section slide-hide-on-mobile">
   <!-- creat a section for slider  and add class  slide-hide-on-mobile-->
    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade  hidden-xs" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="slide.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```